# How to create Snowflake table (dynamically find data types) and load from stage (AWS S3)?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a CSV, about 200 columns and over 200k rows in AWS S3. I need to load into Snowflake via stage.

I did my best to ascertain the data types and "create table" but keep getting stuck on some varchar that exceeds the max value I set. I used a sample and ran through Pandas, which helped but still hitting values that weren't in the sample (so the data type is wrong).

I created a file format like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_csv
  TYPE = CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = '|';

CREATE TABLE GEO_DATA
  USING TEMPLATE (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
      FROM TABLE(
        INFER_SCHEMA(
          LOCATION=>'@LOAD.GEO_DATA',
          FILE_FORMAT=>'my_csv'
        )
      ));
```

It ran but it made everything varchar. There are definitely some number fields in there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you defining a max varchar size for a column? What if you just let Snowflake load the whole string (as long as the max length of the row is ok)

Comment: Oh well because in other RDBMS it's better to use only what you need but now reading that in Snowflake it doesn't matter. You're right, it seems you can use the max without a performance or cost penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the comment to answer:

- Avoid giving strings (varchars) a max length. Snowflake can handle it without a performance penalty - as long as the max row size limits are within the limits.